# Need url for STS for eclipse indigo 3.7

Tags: spring, spring-tool-suite

I need to install STS (Spring Tool Suite) in my eclipse indigo , please advise me which url will work that I can enter in ad new software option , I have just tried through eclipse market place but in the meantime it thorws the error and update was not successfuly applied.

Answer (score 0):

If you had the latest/greatest Eclipse (and, frankly, I encourage you to get it), you can simply drag/drop directly from the STS website into your running Eclipse:

- http://www.springsource.org/sts